# Symfony2 dynamic relationship with a field

Tags: symfony, dynamic, types, field

I am building a social website and I am laying out how the feed will work. I want to use the answer here: [How to implement the activity stream in a social network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443960/how-to-implement-the-activity-stream-in-a-social-network) and implement the database design mentioned:

```
id             
user_id       (int)
activity_type (tinyint)
source_id     (int)  
parent_id     (int)
parent_type   (tinyint)
time          (datetime but a smaller type like int would be better)
```

The problem is I don't know how I would map the `source_id` based off `activity_type`. If a user registers, I want the `source_id` to be the user that registered. If someone creates a group the `source_id` will be the group. I know I can just use simple IDs without keys I just wanted to know if Symfony had some sort of way to do this built in.

If I fetch the feed and the `activity_type` is user_register I would like to be able to do this to get the source (user) without running an additional query:

```
$feedEntity->getSource()->getUsername(); //getSource() being the User entity
```

And if the `source_type`is "user_post":

```
$feedEntity->getSource()->getMessage(); //getSource() being the UserPost entity
```

I basically just want to find the best way to store this data and make it the fastest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easy to deal with doctrine and i think it cannot achieved 100% automatically

However, the keyword is **table inheritance**

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

I think you could achieve your goal by doing something like this :

- You create a discriminator map by the type column of the table which tells doctrine to load this entity a *UserSource* (for example)
- This *UserSource* can be an own entity (can be inherited from a base class if you want) where you can decide to map the source_id column to the real User Entity
- You can use *instanceof* matching against the namespace of the different entities mapped inside your discriminator map to define different behaviours for the different sources

Comment: what is a discriminator map?

Comment: Did you read the content of the link ?

"The @DiscriminatorMap specifies which values of the discriminator column identify a row as being of a certain type. In the case above a value of “person” identifies a row as being of type Person and “employee” identifies a row as being of type Employee."

In short: this map defines which value of your type column will be mapped to which entity

Comment: Yes, I meant to delete that question :/