# How to store (in MySQL) multiple updates in one "activity" of an activity log?

Tags: mysql, database, json, database-design

**What I'm doing** > I am designing a table in my MySQL database that stores the activity of users in my web app. Activities are things like:

- Logging in
- Adding a record
- Editing a record (with multiple things to edit i.e. title, person, date)
- Deleting a record
- Copying a record
- Email sent
- Email received
- Import from an external resource
- Sync with external resource
- Add a user
- Delete a user
- And so on

**The problem** > activities like editing a record can have multiple recordings for one update i.e. editing the title, date and person at the same time.

**I need** > I'd like the flexibility to be able to display descriptions like

> John Doe changed the date from 1/1/14 to 2/3/14 and
>   the title from "old title" to "new title"

I've research previous answers but not been able to find a solution that handles this type of activity log. My proposed solution is based on some ideas in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443960/how-to-implement-the-activity-stream-in-a-social-network).

**I propose** > Here's what I am thinking about building

One table called activity_logs

```
(int) id
(varchar) type (record, user, etc.)
(int) object_id (record_id, user_id, etc.)
(varchar) display_name (user's name, record title, etc.)
(varchar) verb (delete, add, update, copy, login, logout, etc.)
(text) data (see below)
(datetime) created_at
(int) created_by
```

In the case of updating a record I would store detail of the activity in the data field in the following JSON as an example:

```
{
  "date": { "from": "2014-01-01 00:00:00", "to": "2014-03-04 00:00:00"},
  "title": { "from": "old title", "to": "new title"}
}
```

In the case of display name, if a record is deleted I can still display "John Doe deleted 'name of record'" (as the record won't exist anymore)

**My concerns** > I'm concerned that if I build it this way it might give me issues down the line when I come to extend it (issues that I am not aware of yet). This is actually a refactor of existing functionality that I've not built right in the first place...

**So my questions are** > what are the issues with building an activity log this way? And is there a better practice than above?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat multiple concurrent actions as a single "activity", you need two tables: `action` and `activity`. The `activity` table would contain the common elements, such as the user and time. The `action` table would contain fields specific to the action, such as the type of action (delete, update, etc.) and a foreign key to `activity.id`. You can then use a join to get all the actions associated with a particular activity.

Activity table:

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
user_id INT Foreign key references Users.id
time DATETIME
```

Action table could be something like:

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
activity_id INT Foreign Key references Activity.id
verb VARCHAR
target VARCHAR
```

Comment: Could you should me an example scheme of the action table? Are you saying it would be account.id, action_type, from, to?