# How can TINYINT store strings value on MySQL

Tags: mysql, notifications, relational-database, tinyint

So i'm quite new to database structure. And currently i need to build a notifications system for my web application. After googling for awhile i find [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443960/how-to-implement-the-activity-stream-in-a-social-network#) is interesting.

Why activity_type is TINYINT? Doesn't it suppose to be string because he says the example value is like 'added favourite'. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, don't follow that example.

He's using numbers in the `TINYINT` that have magical meanings and most likely represented in his code as constants, so 1 means one kind of activity, 2 means another, etc., and only the code knows those meanings -- not the database.

Then there's the "source_id" that refers to an undeclared, unenforced foreign key referencing one of several other tables.  Don't do this.

Within a database column, all of the values should have the same meaning -- they should all be from the same information domain.  If there's a "thing_id" column, it should always refer to the "id" of a row in the thing table.  It should **not** refer to a row in the "thing1" table sometimes or maybe a row in the "thing2" table other times depending on whether "thing_type" is set to "1" or "2" ... yuck.

There are probably viable use cases for such a design but I would interpret this model as a red flag warning of a database that has no enforcement of referential integrity... and that is not consistent with best practices for relational databases.

Note from his last comment...

> No joins.

He's not really using the relational database as a relational database.  He's using it almost as some kind of key/value store.

Comment: Ok, well said, i get what you mean. So any suggestion for improvement?